# how do i get the hostname of a django application

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a django application running using gunicorn and frontended by nginx. I am trying to get the full hostname of the application because I need to redirect out of the application and need to pass the external application my url so it can pass control back to me. How do I find my hostname/application name. I tried `request.get_host()`, but it gave me `127.0.0.1:8000`

Answer (score 0):

You can access it from the `request` object's `META` attribute.

```
request.META['HTTP_HOST']
```

Comment: No. still gives me 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? If you are, read the big highlighted section here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host